# Can I get methods amount (or list) whose complexity are greater than a certain number by sonar web service API?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I can get complexity by web service API (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions)

But I wanna get method amount (or list) whose complexity are greater than a certain number.

Best Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, method-level metrics are not stored. File-level metrics, including complexity, are.

Comment: are file complexity and class complexity metrics stored?